# OSX: Hiding Cocoa app's temp files from a Posix/shell program: "reverse" sandboxing?

Tags: macos, permissions, filesystems, acl, sandbox

So here is the problem: my app (sandboxed or not, doesn't seem to matter) creates some temp files in NSTemporaryDirectory().
These files are then passed to some Cocoa/Quartz APIs for rendering and doing other stuff (via an NSUrl)
Another constraint that I have is that I cannot run setuid root and cannot impersonate to anyone.

How can make sure that **no other process from the same user** (or any other user) will be able to have access to these files (preferrably not even knowing they exist)?

If I could somehow create a "per-process filesystem", which is only known to my process and not to any other process of the same user, it would have done what I wanted.
Also, I tried using FIFOs, but it seems that Foundation and Quartz classes which request NSUrls, test for file regularity and refuse to let me use FIFOs in this manner.

I need to make sure that the data in these files is kept secret from all other processes on the system, (except root) and from other (POSIX or Cocoa) processes of the user who runs this app.

I tried using ACLs but I don't see how can I specify permissions per process and not per user...

(I'm this close to resorting to writing a driver to do this).

Thanks!
Misha.

Comment: Can you unlink the files once your rendering APIs pick them up, thus reducing the window when the files are present? I think the file will disappear from the directory listing but will continue to work until it's closed.

Comment: Other than that I don't see how you could do this without interposing something at the system level. The nature of a file system is to store files and make them available. Perhaps it would be easier to find a non-URL way to access the Foundation/Quartz functionality you need.

Comment: Thanks! We thought about this but it seems that before the renderer picks it up, it takes a while for the file to be filled... I guess you're right, and there is no way around it without messing with the kernel level.